# Show that $\mathbb{K}\cong M_{n}(\mathbb{K})$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

I would like to show the following isomorphy but not sure how to go about this:

$\mathbb{K}\cong M_{n}(\mathbb{K})$

Also in Blackadar (Operator Algebras, page 171) he states that this isomorphism induces: $B\cong M_{2}(B)$, $M(B)\cong M_{2}(M(B))$ and $Q(B)\cong M_{2}(Q(B))$, which he calls standard isomorphisms.
In the context or the present question, the notation has the following meaning:

- $B$ is a $C^\ast$-algebra,
- $Q$ is the outer multiplier algebra of $B$ (hence $Q = M(B)/B$),
- $M$ is the multiplier algebra,
- $M_{n}(\mathbb{K})$ are $n\times n$ matrices with entries from $\mathbb{K}$, and finally
- $\mathbb{K}$ is the $C^\star$-algebra of compact operators on a separable, infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Anyway, I don't know how to show this and cannot find a reference on how to do this. Would be very thankful for a reference, how to do it or even some hint.

Comment: Please introduce the notation. Otherwise, the question is senseless. (Please don't assume that we have that book at hand.)

Comment: Sorry, just did.

Comment: What is $\mathbb K$?  A field?  Depending on what sort of isomorphism you mean, $\mathbb K \cong M_n(\mathbb K)$ is usually false.

Comment: You still haven't introduced $\mathbb{K}$ (of course everybody understands what is $M_n(K)$ when $K$ is given...)

Comment: Sorry, oversaw it

Comment: Hint: Writing $K(H)$ the algebra of compact operators on the Hilbert space $H$, try to identity $K(H^n)$ with $M_n(K(H))$.

Comment: Intuitvely I would take an element out of the algebra, so a compact operator and write it as a direct sum for example. $A = (1-P)A \oplus PA$. In that case I could put both of the projections as entries of the diagonal of the $M_{2}$ matrix, since they are both compact?

Comment: You may want to work with a explicit description of $H$, such as $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. In such a case you may want to construct $n$ (explicit) copies of $H$ within itself, take unitaries between $H$ and the copies (so isometries from $H$ onto a proper closed subspace) and then conjugate by these. (Another hint: think of the phenomena behind Hilbert's hotel, or Dedekind's definition of an infinite set).

Comment: Is this the equivalence being talked about? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_equivalence

Comment: The other only way I can think about is to copy the operator across the diagonal of the matrix.